# Are the tags/comments in HTML auto-corrected by browsers?

Tags: html, comments, autocorrect

Instead of

```
<!--
```

,
I used

```
<!-
```

...and it is working.

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern browser parsers (i.e. those that use the HTML5 parsing algorithm) work like this. If they are expecting text or a new tag next, and they see `<!` then they check the next few characters to see if they are `--` or `DOCTYPE` or, if they are processing embedded SVG or MathML, `[CDATA[`. (See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tokenization.html#markup-declaration-open-state)

If, as in the case of `<!- foo`, none of these match then the parser enters the [bogus comment state](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tokenization.html#bogus-comment-state) where all the characters following, up to the next `>`, are read and and converted into a comment to be put into the DOM.

Hence the behaviour you see with `<!-` working like a comment start. Note that such behaviour is "repair" behaviour for broken markup and it's wise not to rely on it.

You can see how such markup forms a DOM here: [Live DOM Viewer](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cp%3ESomeText%3C!-%20this%20is%20a%20bogus%20comment%3EMore%20text%3C%2Fp%3E)

Also note that this is different to what @Amber says. It is not treated as a tag in any meaningful sense, and it is certainly not ignored.

Comment: "Treated as a tag" in the sense that it's parsed up to the next `>` (which is the closing character for a tag), rather than the next `-->` (which is the closing character for a comment). "Ignored" in the sense that it's used as a comment, rather than affecting the text of the displayed page.

Answer (score 5):

It's not actually working - it's just interpreting it as an actual tag, and then throwing that tag out as invalid.

```
<!- foo bar -->
```

is treated as a tag, `<!-foo bar-->` which obviously isn't a standard HTML tag, and thus is ignored.

Try this, and you'll see it's not truly working as a comment:

```
<!- >foo bar-->
```

Comment: This leads to another question:
If comments cannot be read by compiler/interpreter,
how do we test that it is NOT getting read (of course, as in my example)?